# Python list multiply and index

Tags: python, list

I create 3 empty list nested in a list, and index to append to the first one, but it results in all the list:

```
In [1]:
   ...: a = [[]] * 3
   ...: a[0].append(3)
   ...: print(a)

Out [1]:
[[3], [3], [3]]
```

My expect output is:

```
[[3], [], []]
```

But if I do this:

```
In [2]:
   ...: b = []
   ...: for i in range(3):
   ...: b.append([])
   ...: b[0].append(3)
   ...: print(b)

Out [2]:
    [[3], [], []]
```

Then I got my expect output

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the first case, you are trying to access the same object (the object and its refernces).

But in the second case, list `a` has totally different -new- objects.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please select it as the right answer :-)